# How to enable syntax highlighting in vi while using the global command?

Tags: command-line, vi, syntax-highlighting

Opening a file with `vi` nicely highlights its contents.

[image: Nicely Highlighted Image]

However, I want to view the file with all lines containing `clock_gettime` hidden. By using the global command `:g!/clock_gettime` I get the required output but it loses all syntax highlighting.

[image: Not Highlighted Image]

Is there a way to view only a set of lines matching (or not matching) the given expression in a way that all visible content is also properly highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only a matter of viewing those lines with highlighting, you could do `:g/clock_gettime/d`

This will actually delete the lines in your editor. When you're done viewing, just do `:q!` so you won't actually delete the lines from the file.